# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts with c# and mono

Tags: c#, mysql, mono

I'm having trouble connecting to the MySql database.  I googled around, but could not find a solution that worked for me.  I have a console app written in c# that works on my localhost.  Connects to the database and just works.  When I then use this app and run it with Mono, I cannot connect to the database.  Thinking it was a permissions issue based on some of my googling, I checked the grants for the user I'm trying to connect with, and it says:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD...
```

(This is me ssh'ing into the machine and checking the grants of its localhost).

So that part is set up correctly.  My coworker has another console app that connects to the database, and I just copied and pasted what they did to connect, but for some reason, I'm not able to connect.  Other there are other troubleshooting things I should look out for?  Thanks.

Comment: `'root'@'localhost'` means you can connect only from localhost. if you want to connect from other machines you must specify those host like `'root'@'hostname'` host name or IP works. you can also use wildcard host like `'root'@'%'` but I never recommend all hosts for atleast root account. check [The MySQL Access Privilege System](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-system.html) and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html

Comment: @bansi I've tried other users as well, not just root, no dice :-\.

Comment: for any user you should specify the hostname/IP also (if you want to connect from anywhere use `%` as hosname part). MySQL uses username, hostname or IP and password to authenticate. If still no luck check if firewall/antivirus is not blocking connection to MySQL Port (default port 3306 - tcp)